# Select com joins retornar último resultado por data

Tags: mysql

Tenho as tabelas drives, documents, e defenders:

Defenders

```
id  | nome      | cpf
1   | Nome 1    | 000000
2   | Nome 2    | 000000
3   | Nome 3    |
```

Drives

```
id   | document_id   | defender_id | data
1    | 123           | 1           | 2014-01-01
2    | 233           | 2           | 2013-05-02
3    | 453           | 1           | 2011-01-05
4    | 543           | 3           | 2014-05-20
5    | 454           | 1           | 2012-12-12
6    | 532           | 2           | 2011-11-05
```

Documents

```
   id    | vigencia   | publicacao
   123   | 2014-01-05 | 2014-01-05 
   233   | 2013-05-02 | 2013-05-02 
   453   | 2011-01-05 | 2011-01-05 
   543   | 2014-05-05 | 2014-05-15 
   454   | 2012-12-13 | 2012-12-13 
   532   | 2011-11-05 | 2011-11-05
```

E meu select:

```
select d.nome, doc.vigencia from defenders d
    join drives dr on dr.defender_id = d.id
    join documents doc on doc.id = dr.document_id
group by nome
order by nome, doc.vigencia desc, doc.publicacao desc, dr.data_hora desc
```

Preciso retornar algo como:

```
id   | nome      | vigencia
1    | Nome 1    | 2014-01-05
2    | Nome 2    | 2013-05-02
3    | Nome 3    | 2014-05-05
```

Ou seja, apenas um registro de cada defenders ordenado pela vigência.
Tentei encontrar de várias formas uma solução, mas falhei em todas.
Usei group by, select MAX(vigencia) etc.

Alguma forma de fazer isso? Eu poderia tratar o resultado pelo PHP, mas se der pra trazer assim com a query, eu prefiro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O fato de ser mysql facilita um pouco.

Eu retornei o **max(vigencia)** e agrupei pelo **Driver.id**. Meu sql ficou assim:

```
select 
  d.id,  
  d.nome, 
  max(doc.vigencia) as vigencia
from Defenders d 
inner join Drives di
  on d.id = di.defender_id
inner join Documents doc
  on di.document_id = doc.id
group by d.id
```

Testei a consulta neste link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6832/1

Comment: Genial! Funcionou perfeitamente. Tentei de tudo, menos isso. Valeu!

Comment: Edgar, como eu havia dito antes, funcionou. Mas acontece que em alguns casos isso não está funcionando, bro. O que sujere? Crio uma consulta no SQLFiddle pra você ver ou coloco as informações aqui mesmo, na pergunta acima?

Comment: @xmdenis faça um fiddle e o alimente com informações para simular o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de um `JOIN` que tal um subselect com `LIMIT 1` e `ORDER BY vigencia`?

Comment: A idéia é boa. Como a solução do Edgar funcionou, depois eu testo essa também, pra questão de conhecimento. Mas, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Para obter o resultado que você deseja basta agrupar pelo ID do defender, e ordenar pelo nome seguido pela data de vigência decrescente:

```
select d.nome, doc.vigencia from defenders d
    join drives dr on dr.defender_id = d.id
    join documents doc on doc.id = dr.document_id
group by d.id
order by d.nome, doc.vigencia desc;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87636/9)

Comment: Acessei o SQLFiddle, e comparei o resultado. Parece que não deu certo. Mas, obrigado.

Comment: @xmdenis o que esta errado?

Comment: @xmdenis me parece que o teu exemplo de como deve ser esta errado, ele mostra a data da tabela drives e não a vigência da tabela documents que seria esse: ` 543   | 2014-05-05 | 2014-05-15 `

Comment: você tem razão. Fiz até a correção no exemplo. Mas, tentei aplicar sua solução em minha base, mas a data de vigência sempre vem a mais antiga. Esquisito. Não consegui enxergar o motivo. Eu até havia tentado isso antes. Enfim, valeu.